# How to design nested 3 level json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object like below:

```
Parent: { Child1: [ {name:'grandchild1', value:'abc', checked:true}, {name:'grandchild2', value:'pqr', checked:false} ], Child2: [ {name:'grandchild3', value:'abcd', checked:false}, {name:'grandchild4', value:'pqrs', checked:true} ], parent2{...........}.... };
```

How can I make it nested JSON.

Just like in root: parent1, parent2...
Child: children1, ....( Corresponding to parent)
Grandchildren: based on children

Please guide me how can I make it?

Comment: Some clarification may be needed here. "`root: parent1, parent2... Child: children1, ....( Corresponding to parent) Grandchildren: based on children`" doesn't look like the structure of 'nested JSON'. (And your original object includes parent2 inside Parent, which seems unusual.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a JSON object you just have to follow [JSON syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

In your example it will look like:

```
{
  "parent": {
       "child1": [{
           "name": "grandchild1",
           "value": "abc",
           "checked": "true"
       }, {
           "name": "grandchild2",
           "value": "pqr",
           "checked": "false"
       }]
   }
}
```

Please note that in JSON, string values must be written with double quotes.

If you need to get JSON string from object programmatically, you can write in javascript:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```